# .matches(regular expression) mistake

Tags: java, regex, swing, keylistener

I have the following code inside a key listener:

```
c = char c = e.getKeyChar();

if(c==KeyEvent.VK_BACK_SPACE) {

    boolean vFormandPresChck = txtAddressLine1.getText().
        matches("((?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-zA-Z]))");
                
    if(vFormandPresChck==true) {
        btnAddAthlete.setEnabled(true);
    } else {
        btnAddAthlete.setEnabled(false);
    }
}
```

As far as I'm aware my regular should make sure the string in the text field has at least 1 letter and one number the backspace key is clicked. However this does not appear to work. For example when the backspace is clicked whilst the string in the textfield is `4 Alder` the Button should stay enabled because the string would be `4 Alde`, but it does not stay enabled. I would greatly appreciate any help with this problem

#### Edit

I have checked this on the regex101 site and that seems to think it should work so would someone be able to clarify if this code is broken or if it is an error in the rest of my code

Comment: The regex seems to be okay.

Comment: What exactly do you try to match? At least one number followed by at least one character? Your regular expression seems to lack the space that is written into your example string.

Comment: So how would I add the space into it? I haven't written one with a space before

Comment: Also just tried without a space in a string and it still doesn't work @Nitram

Comment: Without seeing the actual string it's hard to say.  Just remember:  `matches()` attempts to match the entire string, not just a part of it.  Maybe you want `find()` instead.

Comment: \s is the space character. Please tell me what it is you want to match exactly. I can provide a better answer if you do.

Comment: The text field is for entering a home address so 4 Alder is an actual string which might be inputted @Nitram

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It kind of looks like the regular expression misses the whitespace character you wrote into your examples.

In any case your regular expression looks far more complicated then it has no be. You don't need any group matching to get what you like to do.

Assuming that you want to match a number followed by characters (with a optional space in between) you can use a regular expression looking like this:

```
"[0-9]+\s*[a-zA-Z]+"
```

Using the `matches` the correct.

A short explanation:
This regular expression consists of three components:

1. `[0-9]+` - Any amount of numbers, but at least one
2. `\s*"` - Any amount of white space characters (space, tab, etc.), also no spaces are allowed.
3. `[a-zA-Z]+` - Any amount of capital and non-capital characters, but at least one

You can also do some minor change to enforce something like a capital character followed by any number of capital or non capital characters. This can be done by changing the last part to this: `[A-Z][a-zA-Z]*`

Also if you want your last name component to contain spaces you can add those to the group of allowed characters by just adding `\s` into the square brackets.

So in the end you could end up with something like this:

```
"[0-9]+\s*[A-Z][a-zA-Z\s]*"
```

But that is just a proposal to give you a idea what can be done here.